# Automatically loading new records into page with ajax in rails 3?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to figure out how to load new records into a page through ajax (I assume) - think twitter or gmail. Any ideas where to start with this one?

Also I'm using rails 3, and jquery

Answer (score 0):

Hugely deep topic, so I'll scope my answer to the start part.

Start with loading new records on refresh. This will take a fair bit of development as it is, because you have to track when you last loaded, how many records, are you close to hitting the API rate limiter (is there one), fetching only the new ones from the service and appending to the ones you already have.

Once you've solved all of that and have a working page, we can start talking about how to do it through ajax.

Comment: The page already loads the records without ajax, and if you refresh, the new records appear - this is basic in rails unless I'm misunderstanding your answer?

Comment: No, you're not misunderstanding, but your question didn't indicate that, :)

For the next step, there are a few questions, the first one being "Are you looking to update on an event or is the update time-based?"

Comment: Well I guess on an event - such as a new record has been created. If thats not possible though, polling for changes every 5 minutes or so would be totally fine.

Comment: New record created event would require websockets or some other push technology. See if Faye will do the job. To do polling, the easiest thing to do is to install the jQuery PeriodicalUpdater plugin and use it to poll.